# How to bundle the default ML face model in the app's binary?

Tags: firebase, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I want to use Firebase ML Vision with the default model for face detection.

The Android setup docs discuss downloading model at install time vs detection time:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces#before-you-begin

But I want the model in the app's apk / app bundle. Once the user has downloaded the app from the Play Store, I need it to run without any additional dependencies. Is that possible?

How come the iOS setup docs don't mention anything about downloading the model?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/detect-faces

Also, how many bytes is the face model asset?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it would not be possible to put the predefined face detection model in the apk. 
It may be that firebase does not want the model to be easy to copy or modify, so it does not output it as a file. In addition, they can thereby improve the model continuously.

What you can do is look for the tflite model file on the internet (maybe it's open source anyway and I just did not find it). You can then save this file as a custom model in the assets folder of your android project.
Custom models can be saved both directly in the app and on the firebase server.

Alternatively, you can also look for other (not firebase) tflite face detection models or create one yourself and use it as a custom model.
Here you will find a bunch of models that you can easily use or retrain.
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_models

Probably the hardest part is getting this model file. Then integrating it into firebase should be as easy as seeing it here:

```
FirebaseLocalModel localSource =
        new FirebaseLocalModel.Builder("my_local_model")  // Assign a name to this model
                .setAssetFilePath("my_model.tflite")
                .build();
FirebaseModelManager.getInstance().registerLocalModel(localSource);
```